# DATA SORTING WITH CUSTOM FUNCTION

Tags: python, sorting

I WANTED OUTPUT SORTED BY [A,B,C,D,E] IN THE LIST

```
A =['12,Boring Stuff with Python Programming,D,692617,4.6,70508',
'10,Complete C# 2D,A,364934,4.6,78989',
'5,Java Developers,B,502572,4.6,123798',
'15,Learn Python Programming Masterclass,C,240790,4.5,58677',
'3,Machine Learning A-Z,E,692812,4.5,132228',]
    
def order(string):
        v= []
        for i in string:
            m = i.split(",")
            v.append(m[1])
        return v
    print(sorted(A,key=order))
```

WHEN I I USE 'M[0]', IT SORTED WITH [ 5,3,10,12,15 ] BUT WHEN USING 'M[1]' THE ERROR SHOW

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ts.py", line 82, in <module>
    print(sorted(A,key=order))
  File "ts.py", line 80, in order
    v.append(m[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: What is your question even? If you want the error explained, search for it online to get an idea. As a new user here, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the letters [A B C D E] always fall in the third item, you could do::

```
>>> print(sorted(A, key=lambda x: x.split(',')[2]))
['10,Complete C# 2D,A,364934,4.6,78989',
 '5,Java Developers,B,502572,4.6,123798',
 '15,Learn Python Programming Masterclass,C,240790,4.5,58677',
 '12,Boring Stuff with Python Programming,D,692617,4.6,70508',
 '3,Machine Learning A-Z,E,692812,4.5,132228']
```

Notice the `key` function does not take the whole list, but it takes one item from the list (the string), and returns the part of that string that should be used as they key for comparison.  In this case, the third item counting by commas.  Without `key` it defaults to using the whole item (the string) as they key, functionally speaking the identity function.

Comment: List can't be split, so how "x.split " works

Comment: @Ranjan I think see your confusion.  I will expand my answer to address your question.